# Elasticsearch sort results from several indexes so that one index has priority

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, indexing

I have 6 websites, lets call them A, B, C, D, E & M. M is the master website because from it you can search the contents of others, this I've done easily by using putting all indexes separated by comma in the search query.

However I have a new requirement now, that from every website you can search all websites(easy to do, apply solution from M to all), BUT give priority to results from the current website.

So If I'm searching from C, first results should be from C and then from others based on score.

Now, how do I give results from one index priority over the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [boosting query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-boosting-query.html) serves this purpose well:

### Sample data

```
POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"a"}}
{"message":"First website"}
{"index":{"_index":"b"}}
{"message":"Second website"}
{"index":{"_index":"c"}}
{"message":"Third website"}
{"index":{"_index":"d"}}
{"message":"Something irrelevant"}
```

### Query

```
POST /a,b,c,d/_search
{
  "query": {
    "boosting": {
      "positive": {
        "match": {
          "message": "website"
        }
      },
      "negative": {
        "terms": {
          "_index": ["b", "c", "d"]
        }
      }, 
      "negative_boost": 0.2
    }
  }
}
```

### Response

```
{
  ...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "a",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "sx-DkWsBHWmGEbsYwViS",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "First website"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "b",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "tB-DkWsBHWmGEbsYwViS",
        "_score" : 0.05753642,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "Second website"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "c",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "tR-DkWsBHWmGEbsYwViS",
        "_score" : 0.05753642,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "Third website"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Notes

1. The smaller you make the `negative_boost`, the more likely it is that results from the "active index" will win out over the other indices
2. If you set the `negative_boost` to `0`, you will guarantee that the "active site" results sort first, but you will discard all scores for all the other sites, so the remaining sort will be arbitrary.

I reckon something like `negative_boost: 0.1`, which is an order-of-magnitude adjustment on relevance, should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to limit number of results now? 
Because for searches on which without boosting I would get lets say 600 results, now I get over 1800 which I think is close to the total amount of documents there are, like it doesn't have a "cut off point" anymore. It lists document even if it doesn't have a keyword in it.

Comment: As documented (and as I tested in ES 6.6 and 7.1), the boosting query should only be including results that match the `positive` query clause.  Are you sure that the results don't actually have any of the keywords that you searched for?  Is there any more you can share about the `positive` clause you're using in that query?

Comment: Definitelly not, on this link you can see my unboosted and then boosted query: https://pastebin.com/WeH5iNg7 and here is the last result, 1660th to be exact, it even has a grade of score of 1.5 !!! And it's just a sample empty document that was indexed. However for when searching for "dna" it comes up... https://pastebin.com/ssvcwpX2

Comment: The issue isn't the boosting query, it's the way you've constructed your main bool query.  If you include both `must` clauses and `should` clauses, then `minimum_should_match` effectively defaults to `0` (i.e. - the presence of `must` clauses means that you no longer need at least 1 `should` clause to hit).  I'd suggest making two changes: (#1) Add an explicit `minimum_should_match: 1` to your top-level bool and (#2) Switch your `must` to a `filter` (the date range stuff doesn't seem helpful for scoring/relevance, and filters are cheaper): https://pastebin.com/ZjpZQsM3